# Delete empty tags (non self-closing) in an HTML string

Tags: php, html, regex, tags, domdocument

Does anyone know how I could delete empty tags with PHP ?

- self-closing tags should be ignored
- it should consider empty content (spaces, line breaks, etc)

I did try two things :

with DOMdocument, but the problem is that it considers self-closing tags as empty (images, etc)

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$query = '//*[not(node())]'; //all empty tags
$nodes = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

I also had a try with regexes, but the best one I found on the internet doesn't work for what I need either :

```
//http://regex101.com/r/rD0sI8/1
$pattern = "/<.[^>]*>(\s+|()|(&nbsp;)*|\s+(&nbsp;)*|(&nbsp;)*\s+|\s+(&nbsp;)*\s+)<\/.[^>]*>/i"; 
$content = preg_replace($pattern,'',$content);
```

I guess it have problems with

```
<img...></span>
```

, for example.  That why I would prefer to work with DOMdocument...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove empty tags you can use this regex:

```
<(.*?)\s*.*?>\s*<\/\1>
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/rD0sI8/3)**

Comment: using $pattern = "/<(.*?)\s*.*?>\s*<\/\1>/i"; returns nothing with preg_replace...

Comment: @user782013 it should work are you using the method correctly? Check the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

If it is available or you can install it, you could use the [`php-tidy][1]` extension. That should get rid of your empty tags and fix other errors.

[A simple example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Qy7gIA).

Answer (score 0):

To handle nested empty elements, you could run `preg_replace` until there's nothing left to replace:

```
<?php

$html = 'foo <i></i> bar <img src> <img> <ul><li></li></ul>';

do {
  $input = $html;
  $html = preg_replace('/<(\S+)[^>]*><\/\1>/', '', $input);
} while ($html !== $input);

print $html;
```

Given that parsing HTML with regular expressions is always going to lead to problems, though, it would be better to work with the DOM to remove nodes that a) aren't [known "void" elements in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements) and b) have no text content:

```
<?php

$html = '<div>foo <i></i> bar <img src> <img> <ul><li></li></ul></div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//node()');

$voids = array('area', 'base', 'br', 'col', 'command', 'embed', 'hr', 'img', 'input', 'keygen', 'link', 'meta', 'param', 'source', 'track', 'wbr');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  if (!in_array($node->nodeName, $voids) && !strlen($node->textContent)) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
  }
}

print $doc->saveHTML(); //  <div>foo  bar <img src> <img> </div>
```